# Why does jar file that created by assembly:single cannot find main class ?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a Maven project. The content of pom.xml file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>BestOfferz</groupId>
    <artifactId>BestOfferz</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>BestOfferz</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-web-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.company.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>


    </build>

</project>
```

I create a jar file by the command:

> mvn clean compile assembly:single

and then I try to run the jar extracted by:

> java -cp target/BestOfferz-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
>   com.company.Main

and I get an error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.company.Main

My Main class looks this way:

package com.company;

```
public class Main {
    ....
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
       ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compile is not enough, when creating a JAR, you need to "package", 
i.e call -

```
mvn package
```

Please read here -
[Build lifecyle](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can just say

```
     mvn install
```

or

```
     mvn clean install
```

then your jar is built and executable through

```
     java -jar YourJar.jar
```

Comment: It also doesn't help me. I still get the error that main class is not found.

Comment: Try the maven-shade-plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html#

Comment: I also tried it. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The following pluginRepository made that job:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com</id>
        <url>http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```

It's a direct node of project node.

Thanks to Yair Zaslavsky.